# How do you load a Firefox profile in Selenium 3.3.3

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, geckodriver

- Python: 3.6.0
- Firefox: 53
- Gecko: 0.16.0
- Selenium: 3.3.3

In running the code below my expectation is that the URL should load in Firefox, and the profile should be the one defined in profile. Instead an anonymous profile is loaded every time.

```
from selenium import webdriver
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile("C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Roaming\\Mozilla\\Firefox\\Profiles\\4dyfyi8v.Profile");
binary = FirefoxBinary('C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe');
ff = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile, firefox_binary=binary);
ff.get("http://cbc.ca");
```

I used to do this, but it seems broken now that I've installed the latest Firefox, and Selenium.

```
from selenium import webdriver
fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile();
fp.set_preference("permissions.default.image",2)
driver = webdriver.Firefox(fp);
```

Is there a way to just set preferences in a profile, and launch selenium using that profile? The old way is well documented, but what mechanism has replaced it seems to be hiding in a todo list somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

The Python selenium port unfortunately is a victim of port over-extension obvious (POO), one could say it's a piece of poo. The documentation is outdated and incomplete. Good luck finding answers to simple questions like this one.

So port your project into C# and loading a profile actually works...

In the future I'll avoid coding with a POO port.